# HMVC. Who creates subview?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I want to use HMVC in frontend. I don't understand who creates a subview. For example, I have a main page that contains some views that contains subview.

Suppose, main page created by:

```
   var model = new MainModel(serviceUrl);
   var view = new MainView(element);
   var controller = new MainController(model, view);
```

Views and subviews created analogic triads. Who these triads creates and how in views and main page?